# How to create customize view for rails admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

Currently, I'm working on a project using **rails_admin gem for admin dashboard displaying**. But *view* is *auto generate* according to *Model field*.

I want to **display my on view in admin dashboard**. What is the process of *display custom view into rails admin*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
config.model Utility do
  configure :preview do
    pretty_value do
      util = bindings[:object]
      %{<div class="blah">
        #{util.name} #{util.phone} #{util.logo}
      </div >}
    end
    children_fields [:name, :phone, :logo] # will be used for searching/filtering, first field will be used for sorting
    read_only true # won't be editable in forms (alternatively, hide it in edit section)
  end

  list do
    field :code
    field :priority
    field :preview
  end

  show do
    field :code
    field :priority
    field :preview
  end

  # other sections will show all fields
end
```

With simple configuration just add a `rails_admin` block and write a class method to your model then call that method.

```
app/models/demo.rb
rails_admin do 
  def self.full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Now call this method it will return full_name as for example.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you could modify this to pull in the custom view html from a separate template file, not directly in the config code?

Comment: offcourse, you can do that as long as you have the model object, you can write a method in another template and use that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your own partial:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
 config.model 'Team' do
  edit do
   field :name do
    partial "my_awesome_partial"
   end
  end
 end
end
```

The partial should be placed in your applications template folder, such as `app/views/rails_admin/main/_my_awesome_partial.html.erb`.

The object is available from the partial with `form.object`.
Please [check here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#form-rendering).